# Android onitemclicklistener issues

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, assets, onitemclicklistener

Dont know if I am even doing this right as I am new to android programming but I have set an OnItemClickListener to respond to the users listitem selection by beginning a new intent.

When the user selects whatever article in the listview they should see the corresponding txt file in the new activity.

So in the new activity I have tried to find a way to open the corresponding file in the subfolder of the Assets Folder ....

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
            setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("position");

    TextView news = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
    AssetManager as = getAssets();

    InputStream is;
    try{
        is = as.open(""); <----- !!!
        int bytes = is.available();
        byte[] b = new byte[bytes];
        is.read(b);
        is.close();

        String s = new String (b);
        news.setText(s);
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

.... however i will only succeed in opening a single txt file. 
How can I implement this activity to respond to the OnItemClickListener from the previous activity as shown here...

```
    ls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bArt);
    ls.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), New_Activity.class );
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

... to open the correct .txt file from the Assets Folder

I have been stuck on this for a long time now so my Appreciation points (no cash value) to the functional answer will be unending 
Much Obliged

Comment: What error you are getting? post the logcat.

Comment: Should be int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

Comment: you have the ListView with the filename and you would like to open the  file you pressed on in the second activity?

Comment: No Error Spring Breaker atm it loads a blank activity via the new intent and exactly right blackbelt.

Comment: Looking to see if that will work Rethinavel

Comment: @dharris: I don't see anywhere you are using that `position` in the 2nd activity. And where you are mentioning the `file name` that you want to open?

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
 int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
```

Your `Id` name must same when ever you passing some data between `Activity`.

Comment: Dont know if it may lead to the problem but the variable "position" isnt being used according to the New_Activity

Answer (score 0):

Instead of store the position, store the file name inside the intent. Yon can retrieve it with `AdapterView.getItemAtPosition`

```
ls.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long id) {

        Intent i = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), New_Activity.class );
        i.putExtra("id", av.getItemAtPosition(position));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

In the other activity retrieve the file name and pass this to the `AssetsManager`

```
String  fileName = i.getStringExtra("id");
InputStream is;
    try{
        is = as.open(fileName); <----- !!!
   // other code
   }
```

Comment: Right this method looks promising and I am trying to get it working atm, the application crashed however upon selecting a "title"

Comment: In listview is there is a txtfile name which is also in assets folder??

Comment: yes the strings in the listview are the same as their corresponding text files but in a different format (I use capitals in the Listview but the .txt files are all lowercase)